# How to publish a jcr node using java code?

Tags: java, jcr, magnolia

Is it possible to publish a jcr node by java code in Magnolia? If yes, how can I do it? I'm using magnolia 6.1

Thanks,
Hieu

Answer (score 0):

You can use `info.magnolia.module.activation.commands.ActivationCommand` to do that for you. You can also use it with an Action.